# JHipster - elasticsearch and angular query filetring not worked, return all objects

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, jhipster

how can i perform a simple search query using `elasticsearch` and `angular` (`jhipster` application) i tried this but not worked :

```
  this.someService.query({'id.equals':6}).subscribe(
      (res: HttpResponse<ISomeObject[]>) => this.onSuccess(res.body, res.headers, pageToLoad, !dontNavigate),
      () => this.onError()
    );
```

it should return only one Object that have `id == 6` but it return me all the objects in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reviwing my code very well i found that i m not executing an `elastisearch` query.

i was executing a `jpa` filter. and i haven't haven't set it up (i think at `jdl` file). To do `elasticsearch` i need to do ;

```
this.someService.search({query: 'id:6'})
```